# Write REG_MULTI_SZ with Hex data

Tags: powershell, hex, registry

I am trying to write to a multi string, but using data gleaned from a REG file, so it's in Hex format. I have managed to convert the string to a byte array using the Convert-HexStringToByteArray [here](http://cyber-defense.sans.org/blog/2010/02/11/powershell-byte-array-hex-convert), but that doesn't produce the same result in the registry as loading the REG, so I am thinking that is not actually the right data type to be casting to.
The initial data looks like this

```
"NavigatorLayoutOrder"=hex(7):31,00,30,00,00,00,31,00,00,00,32,00,00,00,33,00,00,00,30,00,00,00,34,00,00,00,35,00,00,00,36,00,00,00,37,00,00,00,38,00,00,00,39,00,00,00,31,00,31,00,00,00,31,00,32,00,00,00,31,00,33,00,00,00,31,00,34,00,00,00,31,00,35,00,00,00,31,00,36,00,00,00,31,00,37,00,00,00,31,00,38,00,00,00,31,00,39,00,00,00,32,00,30,00,00,00,32,00,31,00,00,00,32,00,32,00,00,00,00,00
```

and I have removed the hex(7): off the front, then tried it as a pure string and casting to a byte array, and neither seems to work.
I have found reference to REG_MULTI_SZ being UTF-16le, but my understanding is that this is also the default for PowerShell, so I shouldn't need to be changing the encoding, but perhaps I am wrong there?

EDIT: I also tried this, with again a successful write, but the wrong result.

```
$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
[byte[]]$bytes = $enc.GetBytes($string)
```

Also tried

```
$array = $string.Split(',')
$byte = [byte[]]$array
```

This also puts data into the registry, but the result is not the same as importing the REG. And, everything I am finding keeps pointing at the idea that the REG file is UTF16, so I tried

```
$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
[byte[]]$bytes = $enc.GetBytes($string)
```

both with BigEndianUnicode & Unicode. Not only did it not work, the result is the same which I find odd. Seems like changing the endian-ness SHOULD change the result.

EDIT: To clarify, the input string as taken from the REG file is shown above. I simply removed the **hex(7):** from the front of the data.

The results are seen here, where the second value is what results from PowerShell, while the first is what the REG file produced.
[image]

The code used to produce this was

```
$string = "31,00,30,00,00,00,31,00,00,00,32,00,00,00,33,00,00,00,30,00,00,00,34,00,00,00,35,00,00,00,36,00,00,00,37,00,00,00,38,00,00,00,39,00,00,00,31,00,31,00,00,00,31,00,32,00,00,00,31,00,33,00,00,00,31,00,34,00,00,00,31,00,35,00,00,00,31,00,36,00,00,00,31,00,37,00,00,00,31,00,38,00,00,00,31,00,39,00,00,00,32,00,30,00,00,00,32,00,31,00,00,00,32,00,32,00,00,00,00,00"

$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::BigEndianUnicode
[byte[]]$bytes = $enc.GetBytes($string)

New-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Synchro\Synchro\ProjectConfig" -name:"NavigatorLayoutOrder2" -value:$bytes -propertyType:MultiString -force
```

Using Unicode encoding produces a very slightly different, but still wrong, result.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, the multistring is little endian encoded, so you need `[Text.Encoding]::Unicode`, not `[Text.Encoding]::BigEndianUnicode`. Plus, using `[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes()` on the string from the .reg file (`"31,00,30,00,..."`) would give you a byte array of the *characters* of that string:

- `'3'` → 51, 0
- `'1'` → 49, 0
- `','` → 44, 0
- `'0'` → 48, 0
- …

What you actually want is a byte array of the comma-separated *hexadecimal values* in that string:

- `31` → 49 (character `'1'`)
- `00` → 0 (character `NUL`)
- `30` → 48 (character `'0'`)
- …

Split the string at commas, convert the hexadecimal number strings to integers, and cast the resulting list of integers to a byte array:

```
[byte[]]$bytes = $string -split ',' | ForEach-Object { [int]"0x$_" }
```

Then you can convert that (little endian encoded) byte array to a string:

```
$ms = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($bytes)
```

and write that to the registry:

```
$key  = 'HKCU:\Software\Synchro\Synchro\ProjectConfig'
$name = 'NavigatorLayoutOrder2'
New-ItemProperty $key -Name $name -Value $ms -PropertyType MultiString -Force
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar! That's exactly what I needed.